# Why do we need concept of average velocity and average speed?

Tags: kinematics, velocity, speed

As I was thinking about average speed / velocity, I got curious, why do we need this concept. This average speed / velocity doesn't give accurate information about motion of an object then why it is taught?

Comment: Why are we taught about so many problems involving blocks sliding down inclines?

Comment: If I’m planning to drive across the country, average speed is way more important to me than my speed at any given moment in time.

Comment: @JonCuster why?

Comment: Because how far I get in the next 12 hours is more important than how far I get in the next second.

Comment: @JonCuster that's intuitve. Thanks.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "doesn't give accurate information about motion". If I traveled 70 miles in the last hour, my average speed over the last hour was 70 mph, which is perfectly accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- On the motorway, your passenger asks: "*How fast are you going?*". You look at the speedometer and answer: "*109 km/hr*". Had he asked 1 minute later, then you would have said: "*111 km/hr*". Had he asked 1 minute earlier, then you would have said: "*110 km/hr*". You are telling him the **instantaneous speed**.
- But what if he asks you **afterwards**: "*How fast did we actually go on the motorway?*". Will you now tell him that you are unable to answer, because you did not drive with just one single speed at every single moment? Or will you start listing up all the infinitely many instantaneous speeds at the infinitely many moments? Or will you show him a graph of the varying speed to time?...
  Or will you just tell him: "***On average*** 110 km/hr".

The latter is clearly the only useful description of the motorway trip in this context.

Averages are fine when the details are not important. Any model in physics leaves out some unnecessary details, and you can think of **an average** as a "model" for the trip; a description of the trip in just one number, when more details are not important. If more details *are* important, then the average is a bad "model" - just like a point-particle drawing is a fine model when working on translational motion with Newton's laws, but not when dealing with rotational mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

Average speed has its main meaning in situations

1. when the actual speed is *almost constant in the observed time period,* i.e.
   *it doesn't vary too much in the substantial part of the observed period.*

   (As you can see, it is very subjective — what are “too much” and “substantial part”? Statisticians would probably use something as e.g. 5%.)
2. when *total time is very important*, e.g. the average speed of train, because we may then calculate time for our journey.
3. when teachers in basic school want torture pupils.

Comment: Well 3rd is also the reason why learning become toxic.

Comment: Is learning about average speeds (simple subtraction and division) more torture than learning about instantaneous speeds (differentiation)?

Answer (score 0):

> This average speed / velocity doesn't give accurate information about
>   motion of an object then why it is taught?

Primarily because that's what you'll actually use in the real world.

For example, if you drive for an hour and cover 60 miles, I suspect you'll describe that you were "averaging 60 mph".

I am sure that on such a trip there were times where you drove faster and times when you drove slower - especially if it's on the 401. So one might be inclined to say that the description of "60 mph" isn't accurate, or some such.

But, simply, the instantaneous motion of your car simply isn't important in this description, any more than saying a measurement is "8 eights of an inch" is more or less useful than "an inch".